# glance image-list with specific image name

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-glance

I run this command to get specific nova instance.here in my case "MyProxy-VM"

```
nova list --name MyProxy-VM --fields id |grep MyProxy-VM |cut -f 2 -d "|"
```

It works fine and also bit faster

I want to list specific glance image say "Ubuntu-14.04"

```
glance image-list | grep Ubuntu-14.04 | awk '{print $2;}
```

This command takes time so i want to list specific image.

I didn't find any option for this in openstack docs.
Is there any way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the same results without grep, cut, awk calls. You can use openstack command with additional command line parameters. For example:

```
# openstack server list --name dev -f value -c ID
# openstack image list --property name=centos7 -f value -c ID
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why these commands answer the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.